# How to Loadbalance requests using Twisted Framework?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.web

I have been using following twisted python script to listen for the requests on port 8080 and forward the request to specific IP.

Here is the script:

```
class ServerProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = None
        self.client = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        factory = protocol.ClientFactory()
        factory.protocol = ClientProtocol
        factory.server = self

        reactor.connectTCP('x.x.x.x', 80, factory)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if (self.client != None):
            self.client.write(data)
        else:
            self.buffer = data

    def write(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)
        print 'Server: ' + data.encode('hex')

class ClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.server.client = self
        self.write(self.factory.server.buffer)
        self.factory.server.buffer = ''

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.factory.server.write(data)

    def write(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)
        print 'Client: ' + data.encode('hex')

def main():

    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = ServerProtocol

    reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In class ServerProtocol, After the connection (request) is made , I am forwarding the request to remote IP x.x.x.x on port 80. Now, I want to loadbalance the incoming requests to multiple remote IPs( x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y, z.z.z.z) on port 80. I looked at txLoadBalancer, but could't find any example to fit this in.

Is there any other way I can do this using twisted framework?

(Note:- I want to programmatically loadbalance the requests, please don't suggest me to use third party loadbalancers)

Answer (score 0):

So i think you need to split your architecture with two scripts.
The first one will be load balancer and other will be simple workers.

Or you can use any other load balancer for example [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)